# Why is Outlook crashing when using Office interop?

Tags: c#, outlook, office365, office-interop

I am attempting to utilize Office interop with C#, but I'm having some difficulties. Executing a test like the one I included below seems to work insofar as it launches Outlook and seems to connect with it. The issue is that if I then try to open the Outlook window (it starts hidden in the tray) I get an error message from Outlook saying `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142).` I do not get this error if Outlook was already running before I started my application. Am I doing something incorrectly or is something broken?

```
using System;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace OutlookInteropTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var app = new Outlook.Application();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.2

Office 360 - Outlook Version 1804 Build 9226.2156

Windows 10 Build 17115.1

**EDIT:** Tested this on Windows 7 and could not reproduce crash. I know that I had this working in Windows 10 at some point. I reinstalled my OS and it still crashes. I'm chocking this up to the typical Microsoft user experience unless anyone has any ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: Did you make the app visible?

Comment: @Enigmativity Not sure what you mean. My app works. I can access the Outlook API and do whatever I want. The issue is that when I go to actually open up the already running Outlook from the system tray it, Outlook, crashes **if** Outlook was launched through my program using the interop API.

Comment: Do you call `app.Visible = true;`?

Comment: It would be great to get a [mcve].

Comment: @Enigmativity I *did*.

Comment: @Enigmativity Visible is not a member of the Outlook application object. This is the Outlook API we are talking about here.

Comment: Are you saying that the code you presented is the entirety of your code?

Comment: @Enigmativity it's the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook is a singleton, so creating a new object will return the existing object if Outlook is already running.

In your case you also need to provide namespace to it

```
olApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Namespace ns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
ns.Logon();
```

Comment: Afraid not. This makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I was having the same issue and perhaps it will help someone in the future:
As IAmRajshah mentioned, only one istance of outlook can run, so, if Outlook is open your code `olApp = new Outlook.Application();`will crash, you need to "connect" to the active instance of outlook with somenthing like this `Oulook.Application olApp =  Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;` The link below has a good example of this:

[Get and sign in to an instance of Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-and-log-on-to-an-instance-of-outlook)